# Creating radial grid using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, radar

I need to create a radial grid of polygons (getting larger as the distance from the observer point grows).

Like this [Creating a Radial Sector Overlay in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255750/creating-a-radial-sector-overlay-in-qgis)

But is there a way to do it in ArcGIS Pro?

I can't seem to find anywhere to add the Proportional Circles Plug-In

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge (and I could be wrong) there is no tool that does that off the shelf. But it can be very easily created in a simple model as shown below:

[image: Model]

`pointtable` is something like this:

[image: Pointtable]

Here is the output symbolised by row ID:

[image: Results]